# Sending email using ClientCredentialProvider is failing to find tenant guid

Tags: java, azure, email, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

I am using Microsoft Identity's OAuth 2.0 support to send email using Microsoft Graph.

Created a personal email account as XXXX@outlook.com. Using this account I login to Azure AD and create a tenant there. Used `ClientCredentialProvider` (From msgraph-sdk-auth-java) as authorizer trying to send an email to myself.
Steps:

1. Created a Tenant account.
2. Created an application and given permission in Graph>Application->Send.email etc
3. Created a Secret key

Below is the error I am getting:

> POST [microsoft.graph.sendMail](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/microsoft.graph.sendMail)
>   SdkVersion : graph-java/v1.5.0 Authorization : Bearer
>   _xv1yPye...

```
{
  "message": {
    "subject": "Test",
    "body": {
      "contentType": "text",
      "content": "The new cafeteria is open bujji."
    },
    "toRecipients": [
      {
        "emailAddress": {
          "address": "xxxxx@outlook.com"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "saveToSentItems": true
}401: UnauthorizedStrict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000Cache-Control: privatex-ms-ags-diagnostic: {
  "ServerInfo": {
    "DataCenter": "South India",
    "Slice": "SliceC",
    "Ring": "3",
    "ScaleUnit": "001",
    "RoleInstance": "AGSFE_IN_1"
  }
}client-request-id: 01565263-11b4-45f7-b089-06f57fdd8241request-id: 2e0cac3b-dc32-4dab-bb30-769590fc156eContent-Length: 361Date: Tue,
16Jun202007: 14: 42GMTContent-Type: application/json{
  "error": {
    "code": "OrganizationFromTenantGuidNotFound",
    "message": "The tenant for tenant guid \u002706841624-5828-4382-b0a0-XXXXXX87b08f\u0027 does not exist.",
    "innerError": {
      "requestId": "01565263-11b4-45f7-b089-06f57fdd8241",
      "date": "2020-06-16T07:14:43",
      "request-id": "2e0cac3b-dc32-4dab-bb30-769590fc156e"
    }
  }
}
```

---

```
private static void sendEmail() {
    ClientCredentialProvider authProvider = new ClientCredentialProvider(
        "fb7f0ecc-b498-XXXX-XXXX-b016f252ea7d",
        Arrays.asList("https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"),
        "8-rpF8sOwV.CWF~7gK.XXXXXXXX.SSScxj0",
        "06841624-5828-4382-b0a0-XXXXXXe87b08f",
        NationalCloud.Global);
    IGraphServiceClient graphClient = GraphServiceClient.builder().authenticationProvider(authProvider).buildClient();

    Message message = new Message();
    message.subject = "Test";
    Ite * mBody body = new ItemBody();
    body.contentType = BodyType.TEXT;
    body.content = "The new cafeteria is open.";
    message.body = body;
    LinkedList < Recipient > toRecipientsList = new LinkedList < Recipient > ();
    Recipient toRecipients = new Recipient();
    EmailAddress emailAddress = new EmailAddress();
    emailAddress.address = "xxxxx@outlook.com";
    toRecipients.emailAddress = emailAddress;
    toRecipientsList.add(toRecipients);
    message.toRecipients = toRecipientsList;
    graphClient.me()
        .sendMail(message, true)
        .buildRequest()
        .post();
}
```

Comment: Hi, do you have a chance to look into my answer? If you have any further questions, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: Have answered your new question:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want to use Microsoft Graph API to send email from your personal account email `XXXX@outlook.com`.

But when you use this account to login to Azure AD and create a tenant, and use `ClientCredentialProvider` in your code, the account will be treated as a work account (not personal account) of your tenant.

So when a work account wants to send an email, it will requires an Exchange online license of O365 subscription. You don't have O365 subscription with Exchange online license. That is why you get this error: `The tenant for tenant guid \u002706841624-5828-4382-b0a0-XXXXXX87b08f\u0027 does not exist.`

If you want to send email from your personal account, it's unnecessary to create an AAD tenant. And you should use [Authorization code provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?context=graph%2Fapi%2F1.0&view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=Java#authorization-code-provider) rather than [Client credentials provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?context=graph%2Fapi%2F1.0&view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=Java#client-credentials-provider). Another thing is that personal account requires Delegated permission rather than Application permission based on [Send mail permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-sendmail?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions). Create an application and give permission in **Graph > Delegated > Mail.Send**.

Please note it may require the scopes as `https://graph.microsoft.com/mail.send` instead of `https://graph.microsoft.com/.default`.

Comment: You are saying when I  use personal account 1). no need to  create a Tenant 2.) Create an  application and give delegated permission. 3.) Use the constructor without tenant ID in Authorization code Provider.

Comment: @bibhutik Oh I'm sorry for a mistake. You need to create a tenant so that you can create an application and give delegated permission. But you should configure the value of the authority as `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common` instead of `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{your tenant}`. By using `common` it will treat your account as a personal account.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, Allen  for your help. I am  able to  send and receive emails from my outlook account. Using **Authorization code provider**
1. Login to Azure AD create an  Application in "Application  from  Personl account".
2. Give permission **Graph > Delegated > Mail.Send**.
3. Provided Redirect URL as http://localhost:8080/muapp".Note Down all appId,Create a secret  Key.
4.Now  hit the below URL with the details

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=40fcd457-1807-49e3-8bce-XXXXXX40ca194&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https://localhost/myapp/&response_mode=query&scope=openid%20offline_access%20https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2Fmail.send%20https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2Fmail.read&state=12345
```

5. Acquire the code.This code we need to pass in **Authorization code provider**.
6.Scope "https://graph.microsoft.com/mail.send"
7. Authority "https://login.microsoftonline.com/consumers"

I have one question every  time send an email I  have to Acquire the code. Is there any Way this will have expiry  date etc.???

Comment: I don't think you have to Acquire the code every time send an email. Just use the `graphClient`. The default life time of an access token is one hour. Besides, if my answer is helpful, you should mark my answer, not yours, which can encourage others to help you.

Comment: @AllenWu Now I have work account enabled. But it require full_access permission  to access any  emailbox using EWS, Which is big security  risk. Can you help me how we can leverage ClientCredentialProvider  or anything else without full_access? My  Application is a demon application.