# Azure Microsoft Graph - Authentication Error

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

{"error":{"code":"OrganizationFromTenantGuidNotFound","message":"The tenant for tenant guid
'' does not
exist.","innerError":{"requestId":"85c28cda-98w7-4c7a-89dd-0962a200ad81","date":"2020-12-17T06:24:44"}}}

Comment: By seeing the above error message it the tenant id you are passing is not the valid one and Please share more details like how you are trying to access the Graph, if any specific graph API request its failing

Answer (score 0):

If the Azure AD account doesn't have O365 subscription, the error will be caused. Try to follow the steps in this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54350260/13308381) and the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/license-users-groups?context=/azure/active-directory/enterprise-users/context/ugr-context) about assigning licenses .

If you call the graph API with `/me` endpoint but you get the access token by [client credentials flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow)(the access token is application identity but not user identity), you need to replace `/me` with `/users/{id | userPrincipalName}` **or** use [authorization code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow) to obtain access token.

For more details, you could refer to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62421172/13308381).